# C++ memory order for consistently storing in atomic variable from multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, memory-barriers

Running the following code hundreds of times, I expected the printed value to be always `3`, but it seems to be 3 only about ~75% of the time. This probably means I have a misunderstanding about the purpose of the various memory orders in C++, or the point of atomic operations. My question is: **is there a way to guarantee that the output of the following program is predictable?**

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int main () {
  std::atomic<int> cnt{0};
  auto f = [&](int n) {cnt.store(n, std::memory_order_seq_cst);};

  std::vector<std::thread> v;
  for (int n = 1; n < 4; ++n)
    v.emplace_back(f, n);

  for (auto& t : v)
    t.join();

  std::cout << cnt.load() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

For instance, here's the output statistics after 100 runs:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++20 -Wall foo.cpp -pthread && for i in {1..100}; do ./a.out; done | sort | uniq -c
      2 1
     21 2
     77 3
```

Comment: Why do you expect this to always be 3? Knowing that might help us correct your misunderstanding.

Comment: You seem to believe that the three threads must run one by one, in the order they were created. If that were the case, there would be little point in having threads to begin with; running simultaneously is kinda the reason they exist.

Comment: The entire purpose of threads is to allow independent forward progress at whatever rate the system can optimally provide. Why use threads if this is not what you want or expect? If you want to do three things in a precise order, why not have a single thread do all three things?

Comment: All great questions; I think I mainly expected that using atomics would make the result predictable. Maybe that's my misunderstanding of what "well-defined behavior" means. If the answer result was split equally three ways, I would also understand that, but 75% 3, 20% 2, and a couple of 1s didn't seem well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

What you observe is orthogonal to memory orders.

The scheduler cannot guarantee the order of execution of threads with the same priority. Even if CPUs are idle and the threads are assigned to different CPUs, cache misses and lock contention can make threads stall relative to threads on other CPUs. Or, if CPUs are busy running other threads with same or higher priority, then your new threads will have to wait till the running threads exhaust their time slices or block in the kernel, whatever happens earlier is hard for the scheduler to predict. Only if your system has one CPU the new threads will run in expected order relative to each other because they will form one queue on one CPU.

`std::memory_order_relaxed` is enough here, since you don't require any ordering between the store to `cnt` and stores/loads to other non-atomic variables. `std::atomic` is always atomic, `std::memory_order` specifies whether loads and stores to other non-atomic variables can be reordered relatively to the load or store of an `std::atomic` variable.